# Can my 3.2V LiFePo4 battery power my cell phone through the cell phone's micro USB port?

Tags: batteries, lifepo4

I have a large LiFePo4 battery cell made by Headway (model 40152S 15AH single CELL, 3.2v).  I'd like to use it to power my Samsung Galaxy S3 phone.  On the original phone battery it says that it is a 3.8v.  The phone has a micro USB input to charge the phone.

I bought a cable that has a Micro-B connector at one end.  I haven't cut it yet, but after cutting the cable I'm hoping that there will be about 4 or 5 wires, where one of them would be for the positive and one for the negative power.

Can I use this 3.2v battery to power the phone even though the battery that comes with the phone works with 3.8v? Will using just the two power leads be enough to make the phone work?

If my headway battery is too low of a voltage to work, would I need to use a 3.7 volt Li-ion battery instead?  Is 3.7v close enough?  I haven't been able to find any batteries that are exactly at 3.8 for a single cell.

edit after searching for a DC-DC Regulator Module:

I found a module that is designed to do this:

Step up DC-DC regulator 
Designed for convert 1 cell Li-Ion / LifEPO4 battery pack to 5.0VDC output
Running / charging most popular 5.0VDC devices such as cell phone/MP3/MP4/PDA/iPod/PSP/GPS from Li-Ion / LifEPO4 battery pack

Input Voltage
2.0 ~ 4.2VDC  via "VIN+" / "VIN-" Soldering spot

Output Voltage
 5.0VDC 2.0A Max via USB Female Jack 
5.0V 1.0A Max each

Will this module be enough to place between my 3.2V battery and the cable that I can use to go from the USB in the regulator to the micro USB on the phone?

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: The answers in this remotely related tread ["Is it possible to charge one phone off another?"](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/101381/7036) may help you get better understanding about what a charging circuit in a cell phone expects.

Comment: Maybe it will work, but probably it will not. Even when internal battery would be disconnected and the phone would not care about input voltage, the highest internal power rail is probably 3.3V which is higher than LiFePo voltage.

Answer (score 1):

The USB port on the phone expects 5 volts in. I doubt the phone will do anything if you give it less than 4.5 volts or so, though it might be possible.

But if you were to use a boost regulator to generate 5 volts from the external battery, at least that would work for powering the phone. Connecting to the +5V and ground lines of the USB connection should be enough, but phone chargers also connect some resistance to the data lines (or connect them together) to indicate that they're a charger instead of a real USB host.

Comment: I found a module that is designed to do this:

Step up DC-DC regulator Designed for convert 1 cell Li-Ion / LifEPO4 battery pack to 5.0VDC output Running / charging most popular 5.0VDC devices such as cell phone/MP3/MP4/PDA/iPod/PSP/GPS from Li-Ion / LifEPO4 battery pack

Input Voltage
2.0 ~ 4.2VDC via "VIN+" / "VIN-" Soldering spot

Output Voltage
5.0VDC 2.0A Max via USB Female Jack 5.0V 1.0A Max each

Will this module be enough to place between my 3.2V battery and the cable that I can use to go from the USB in the regulator to the micro USB on the phone?

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Yes, that sounds perfectly suited for this use. You don't even need to modify a USB cable :)

Answer (score 0):

It is an USB port. USB specifications say 5.00±0.25 V (pre-3.0) for high-power ports and 5.00+0.25-0.55 V for low-power ports; 5.00+0.25-0.55 V (USB 3.0) for the supply voltage (taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) and [usb.org](http://usb.org/developers/docs/usb20_docs/#usb20spec) respectively). So anybody designing the charging circuit in a cell phone would stick to those values. Your approach is most likely going to fail. Besides the fact that Li-ion batteries require special charging you cannot expect a 3.2V source to charge a 3.8V battery (think of water not flowing up the hill...).

Before throwing out your new LiFePo battery right now however you might consider getting a DC-DC step-up boost converter (variable input to 5V output). There are pre-assembled modules available (but I cannot recommend any).

Comment: The Wikipedia article must be mistaken. The original USB power specification is 5.0 V +/- 10%, which is +/- 0.5V.

Comment: USB 2.0 Spec (from http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/usb20_docs/#usb20spec) state 4.75 to 5.25 V for high-power ports and 4.4 to 5.25 V for low-power ports. USB 3.0 is afaik a little more generous. But no matter what the values are, they will be higher than the voltage provided by the above mentioned battery!